# FormatException on IsolatedStorage Read

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have some items stored in the Application settings. And when I do this

`this._userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;`

I get a `System.FormatException`. How do I figure out what is causing it when I read? I'm assuming something is in IsolatedStorage that shouldn't be there.

Here is the stack.

```
 at System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDouble(String s)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadContentAsDouble()
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.XmlWrappedReader.ReadContentAsDouble()
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsDouble()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.ReadValue(Type type, String name, String ns, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context, XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.ReadMemberAtMemberIndex(ClassDataContract classContract, Object& objectLocal, DeserializedObject desObj)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.ReadClass(DeserializedObject desObj, ClassDataContract classContract, Int32 membersRead)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.Deserialize(XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.InitializeCallStack(DataContract clContract, XmlReaderDelegator xmlReaderDelegator, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext xmlObjContext, XmlDictionaryString[] memberNamesColl, XmlDictionaryString[] memberNamespacesColl)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, DataContract& dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.Reload()
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings..ctor(Boolean useSiteSettings)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.get_ApplicationSettings()
   at ShowSeek.Custom_Classes.StateManager.SetupState()
   at ShowSeek.App.Application_Activated(Object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.FireActivated(Boolean isExecutionContextPreserved)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Execution.NativeEmInterop.FireOnResume(Boolean isExecutionContextPreserved)
```

Comment: It would help if you'd post the complete stack trace and the message...

Comment: Might also help to define the type of _userSettings

Comment: The type is of IsolatedStorageSettings.

Comment: Looks like it fails to deserialize something you previously put inside IsolatedStorageSettings. I wonder how it is possible. Could it be that you changed the phone's language at some point then restarted the app?

Comment: If this is the case, how do I handle this?

Comment: No, I couldn't reproduce the issue, it must be something else. When the exception occurs, double click on the first line of the callstack (System.Double.Parse) to activate it. Then open the quickwatch window (shift + F9), type `s` (the name of the first parameter of the Double.Parse method), click on "Reevaluate", then please tell us the value displayed.

Comment: i'm getting not a number or "NaN".

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the problem, but the exception seems to be catched. Does that exception crash your app?

Comment: It is causing a lot of trouble during tombstoning because when the app is trying to restore it's settings from tombstoning, it blows up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm setting this as a first chance exception which isn't crashing the application. But at time, it is happening a lot. and I worry this will impact performance.

Comment: It happened to me when I was trying to access IsolatedStorage in concurrent threads

Answer (score 0):

The function double.Parse, in Windows Phone Silverlight, is implmented as follows:

```
public static double Parse(string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    NumberFormatInfo.ValidateParseStyleFloatingPoint(style);
    NumberFormatInfo instance = NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider);
    double result = 0.0;
    try
    {
        Number.ParseDouble(s, style, instance, true, ref result);
        return result;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        string str = s.Trim();
        if (str.Equals(instance.PositiveInfinitySymbol))
        {
            return PositiveInfinity;
        }
        if (str.Equals(instance.NegativeInfinitySymbol))
        {
            return NegativeInfinity;
        }
        if (!str.Equals(instance.NaNSymbol))
        {
            throw;
        }
        return NaN;
    }
}
```

Basically, it first tries to read your double as a number. Then if it fails it will try the special cases (infinity, NaN). That's how the method is implemented, there's nothing you can do about it. The performance impact should be negligible, especially since it occurs only once in application lifetime (the first time you try to  `accessIsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings`).

Answer (score 0):

Your previous settings probably have changed ( class definition has changed for example).

Use:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Clear();
```

to empty your previous stored settings. Don't forget to comment to code after you have used it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error which was resolved when I used passed InvarientCulture as IFormatProvider

```
Convert.ToDouble(Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```