# FormatException with IsolatedStorageSettings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have a problem when serializing a `Dictionary<string,Person>` to IsolatedStorageSettings. I'm doing the following:

```
public Dictionary<string, Person> Names = new Dictionary<string, Person>();

if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Names"))
        {
            //Add to dictionary
            Names.Add("key", new Person(false,
                new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(0, 0),
                new List<GeoCoordinate>() 
                {
                    new GeoCoordinate(35.8974, 14.5099),
                    new GeoCoordinate(35.8974, 14.5099),
                    new GeoCoordinate(35.8973, 14.5100),
                    new GeoCoordinate(35.8973, 14.5099)
                }));
            //Serialize dictionary to IsolatedStorage
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("Names", Names);
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        }
```

Here is my Person class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Unlocked { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<GeoCoordinate> Bounds { get; set; }

    public Person(bool unlocked, GeoCoordinate location, List<GeoCoordinate> bounds)
    {
        this.Unlocked = unlocked;
        this.Location = location;
        this.Bounds = bounds;
    }
}
```

The code works the first time, however on the second run I get a `System.FormatException` at the if condition. Any help would be highly appreciated thanks.

P.S.: I tried an IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Clear() but the call to `Clear` also gives a `FormatException`.

I have found something new...the exception occurs twenty-five times, or at least that's how many times it shows up in the Output window. However after that, the data is deserialized perfectly. Should I be worried about the exceptions if they do not stop the execution of the program?

EDIT: Here's the call stack when the exception occurs:

```
mscorlib.dll!double.Parse(string s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.IFormatProvider provider) + 0x17 bytes  
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDouble(string s) + 0x4b bytes    
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadContentAsDouble() + 0x1f bytes  
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.XmlWrappedReader.ReadContentAsDouble() + 0xb bytes  
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble() + 0x35 bytes   
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsDouble() + 0x19 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, bool isBinderDefault, System.Reflection.Assembly caller, bool verifyAccess, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)   
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x168 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object obj, object[] parameters) + 0xa bytes   
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.ReadValue(System.Type type, string name, string ns, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader) + 0x138 bytes 
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.ReadMemberAtMemberIndex(System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract classContract, ref object objectLocal, System.Runtime.Serialization.DeserializedObject desObj) + 0xc4 bytes    
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.ReadClass(System.Runtime.Serialization.DeserializedObject desObj, System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract classContract, int membersRead) + 0xf3 bytes 
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.Deserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context) + 0x36 bytes 
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReader.InitializeCallStack(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract clContract, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator xmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext xmlObjContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[] memberNamesColl, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[] memberNamespacesColl) + 0x77 bytes    
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context) + 0x5d bytes  
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract dataContract, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator reader) + 0x3 bytes  
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator reader, string name, string ns, ref System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract dataContract) + 0x10e bytes  
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, System.Type declaredType, System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract dataContract, string name, string ns) + 0xb bytes   
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, bool verifyObjectName) + 0x124 bytes 
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator reader, bool verifyObjectName) + 0xe bytes 
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader reader) + 0x7 bytes 
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(System.IO.Stream stream) + 0x17 bytes  
System.Windows.dll!System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.Reload() + 0xa3 bytes  
System.Windows.dll!System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.IsolatedStorageSettings(bool useSiteSettings) + 0x20 bytes 
System.Windows.dll!System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.get() + 0xd bytes
```

Comment: It's probably this exception, in which case you can safely ignore it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10790113/869621 Just to make sure, could you provide the full call stack?

Comment: So I had to add an XNA Rectangle to my Person class and the number of FormatExceptions blew up. So much so that my game hangs for about five seconds until the exceptions stop. Any ideas about this? I can't leave it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like GeoCoordinate might not be serializable. You could try creating your own class with two doubles for the storage and then convert them back on retrieval.

Comment: You're right that was it. I created a SerializableGeoCoordinate class containing two doubles and added a helper method that creates a SerializableGeoCoordinate from a standard GeoCoordinate. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you code will run exception free without saving to IsolatedStorage. Then you could try just setting the value rather than doing an add.

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
settings["Names"] = Names;
settings.Save();
```

Comment: Already tried that, the code throws a KeyNotFoundException hence you ultimately would still have to call Add() in the catch.