# Isolated Storage - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have two pages in my project. First page is about to create MyPoint object then add it to List and finally save it to Isolated Storage as below:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

Points class:

```
   public class MyPoint
    {

        public Ellipse Point { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public GeoCoordinate Coords { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public MyPoint() { }

        public MyPoint(Ellipse point, GeoCoordinate cords, string tag, string city, string postalCode)
        {
            this.Point = point;
            this.Coords = cords;
            this.Tag = tag;
            this.City = city;
            this.PostalCode = postalCode;
        }
    }
```

Save to Isolated Storage method:

```
private void SaveAppSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                appSettings.Remove("points");
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                appSettings.Add("points", this.points);
                appSettings.Save();   // this throws an Exception
            }
            catch { };
        }
```

Secound`s page load method

```
try
        {
            List<MyPoint> points = (List<MyPoint>)appSettings["points"];
            foreach (MyPoint p in points)
            {
                source.Add(new PointsBook(p.Tag, p.Coords, p.City, p.PostalCode));
            }
        }
```

The point is

appSettings.Save() thorws an exception, even if I comment this line all is working. I have saved points and I can read them throught those two pages.

The problem is when I close the application my appSetting has a string "points" but nothing inside. It just has ["key"] but no [value].

Comment: What is appSettings ? add everything in Question

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13571938/869621

Comment: Anyway I removed GeoCorrdinate from MyPoint property - still not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved!!

MyPoint object had Ellipse in the constructor. IsolatedStorage threw exception about UIElement cannot be serialized.

Everything is working fine now !

Comment: MyPoint looks like it belongs to the "Model" part of the application while the ellipse belongs to the "View", it's not a good idea to keep them together